splitting matrix in multiple blocks
I have a matrix like that below:
A= [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

and I want to extract submatrices containing equal rows. I don't know a priori how many blocks I'll get and the position of equal rows, since it is an example for a much bigger matrix.
The result I should obtain is in the form
B=[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]

C= [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

I tried with

for i in range(len(A)):  
    for j in range(i + 1, len(A)): 
        if np.array_equal(A[i], A[j]):
           cluster = np.vstack((A[i], A[j]))
           print(cluster)

but of course I only get separate couples of equal rows and not a single block.

Do the "equal rows" need to be contiguous? If row 4 and row 7 are equal, should they be lumped together?

The output of the following program will be a dict in which the keys being the name of the sub-matrices viz., B, C.. etc. And the values will be sub matrices with similar rows
A= [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

# initiate variables i and dct, L being length of the matrix A
i, L, dct = 0, len(A), {}

# a list 'ref' to find out whether a row is already listed into sub-matrix
ref = []

while i < L:
    sub = []

    #Execute only if a row is not present in ref
    if A[i] not in ref:
    
        #Another list to iterate over which doesn't contain A[i]
        B = A[:i] + A[i+1:]
        
        for j, y in enumerate(B):
            if A[i] == y: sub.append(y)
            
            # if j is the last index in B, append A[i] to both sub and ref
            if j == len(B)-1:
                sub.append(A[i])
                ref.append(A[i])
        
        # Key of the dct being capital alphabets from 'B' and value being submatrix
        dct[chr(65 + len(ref))] = sub
    i += 1
print(dct) 

#Output: {'B': [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], 'C': [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]}


A normal format for matrix in python is what I've mentioned only.(i.e nothing but the format of multi-dimentional list.) If you are using numpy, Convert it back to 2d-list using A.to_list()

If I understand your code and intentions correctly, the issue is that you are printing the result when you find a pair match (if np.array_equal(A[i], A[j])), and don't wait until you find a non matching pair to return.
The simplest strategy is simply to compare each row with the next one and when you don't get a match, spit out all the rows so far. You can do that in a for loop, a recursive function or a generator. Here's the loop version:
sub_arrays = []
start_index = 0
for i, (row, nextrow) in enumerate(zip(A, A[1:])):
    if not (row==nextrow).all():
        sub_arrays.append(A[start_index:i+1])
        start_index = i+1
        
sub_arrays.append(A[start_index:])

Here sub_arrays is a list that's gonna contain the sub-matrices, you can replace that with a print statement if you like.
Some added comments

it's more pythonic to iterate over the rows of A by doing for row in A than for i in range(len(A)): row = A[i].
in python 3.10+ you can replace zip(A, A[1:]) with itertools.pairwise(A).
from your code, I assume you only want to cluster together rows that are equal and contiguous. If not, the answer looks quite a bit different.
I used numpy in my solution since you were already using it, but it also assumes A is a numpy array. If you don't want to assume that, here's a pure python solution. It relies on list comparison, if you are not sure you can rely on that, add some extra checks for your usecase.

sub_arrays = []
start_index = 0
for i, (row, nextrow) in enumerate(zip(A, A[1:])):
    if not row==nextrow:
        sub_arrays.append(A[start_index:i+1])
        start_index = i+1
        
sub_arrays.append(A[start_index:])


Try:
import numpy as np
from functools import cmp_to_key
from itertools import groupby

A = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]


def fn(row1, row2):
    if np.allclose(row1, row2):
        return 0
    return 1


groups = []
for _, g in groupby(A, cmp_to_key(fn)):
    groups.append(list(g))

print(groups)

Prints:
[
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    ],
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ],
]


Is this what you are looking for?
import numpy as np

# Input matrix A
A = np.array([
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
])

# Find unique rows and their indices
unique_rows, indices = np.unique(A, axis=0, return_index=True)

# Get the unique rows
unique_A = A[np.sort(indices)]

# Print the unique rows
print("Unique Rows:")
print(unique_A)

# Split the unique rows into B and C
B = unique_A[unique_A[:,5] == 0]
C = unique_A[unique_A[:,5] == 1]

# Print B and C
print("\nB:")
print(B)
print("\nC:")
print(C)

Result:
Unique Rows:
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

B:
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]

C:
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

